# change color on bootstrap using vue.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

wen i run this script with vue.js and bootstrap ( vertical tab )

```
<vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description" >      
  <div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.line_info" :key="index">
    <v-tab :title="siteObject.line_info[index].lineid">
      <div class="description text-left">
        <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
          <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
        </small>
      </div>
    </v-tab> 
  </div>     
</vue-tabs>
```

I have this result

> nsn 0102753206
>
> upk 1018.0-1/2
>
> status ACTIVE
>
> lex_id 79VOLGUTD

What can i do that when status is Active then is all text is red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description" >
     <div  v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.line_info" :key="index">
        <v-tab :title="siteObject.line_info[index].lineid">
            <div class="description text-left" :class="{ 'text-danger': item.status === 'ACTIVE' }">
                <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
                    <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
                </small>
                <pre>{{item.status}}</pre>
            </div>

        </v-tab>

    </div>

  </vue-tabs>
```

and style

```
<style scoped>
  .text-danger {
    color: red !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Class & Style bindings?](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Add `:class="{ 'text-danger': status === 'Active' }"` to the element you want to apply your red text to.

Then create your `.text-danger` in your css.

---

In this example we are essentially saying:

IF `status` is equal to `Active` EXACTLY, Add a class of `text-danger`

Comment: i add the class juste after <vue-tabs> and creat css <style>
 .redTextClass { color:red; }
</style> nothing changes

Comment: thank you for your help am new with this stuff can you help me more please with my example ?  i mean the same thing but without button many thanks

Comment: @Sofiane it looks to me that you want it to match `ACTIVE` and not `Active`? based on the data that you've presented above. Have you tried that?

Comment: Are you using Vue devtools? What is status showing as there? What are you applying the class to?

Comment: am using it what should i take look props data or computed ?

Comment: @Sofiane wherever your `status` is defined

Comment: yes wen i write this <pre>{{item.status}}</pre> i have the status